# x64 Memory Pointer and Addressing modes

Tags: disassembly, debugging, windbg

I'm working through example from a Windows disassembly training guide. In the exercise ***rax is set to a byte ptr***, then ***rbx a word ptr***. I notice the next byte of memory is skipped before ***rcx is to a dword ptr***. Why did a byte of memory get skipped? Is there some alignment requirement?

[image: Addressing modes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason to align the data is for performance (some architectures will fault on misaligned data, but since you tagged this with windbg, we will assume amd/intel x64 + windows).

Quoting from the AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume 1:

> The AMD64 architecture does not impose data-alignment requirements for
>   accessing data in memory. However, depending on the location of the
>   misaligned operand with respect to the width of the data bus and other aspects of the hardware implementation (such as
>   store-to-load forwarding mechanisms), a misaligned memory access can
>   require more bus cycles than an aligned access. For maximum
>   performance, avoid misaligned memory accesses.

Ideally the word-sized data (pointed via rbx) would be 2-byte aligned, but as noted above, it is not required.